# Selenium tests crash randomly while executing javascript

Tags: php, javascript, selenium, phpunit, webdriver

I am writing functional tests for Zend application. I run them using PHPUnit and this wrapper : https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP

I run selenium standalone server from jar file locally (v2.19.0). I use a lot of js and ajax in this app, so I made a waitForAjax function in my FunctionalTestCase class, so I can wait until all data is loaded properly. It uses $.active, as I am using jQuery ajax functions. The function looks like that:

```
public function waitForAjax($timeout = 10) {
  sleep(1);
  for($i = 0 ; $i < $timeout - 1 ; $i++) {
    $active = $this->getJsResult('return $.active;');

    if($active > 0) {
      sleep(1);
    }else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Function getJsResult executes execute_js_sync from WebDriver wrapper and gets the result from Selenium response.

My problem is as follows : selenium randomly hangs on executing js on the site. Sometimes it returns almost instantly, but most of the time it just stays on executing script. This is the only output from the server:

```
11:58:48.386 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return $.active;, []] at URL: /session/1334915841900/execute)
```

What bothers me the most is why is this happening so randomly?

I could really use some help here.

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: When your tests hang what Firebug console > Errors says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had when I used Selenium first too that it randomly crashes and I saw that it was eating many RAM and hitted the maxiumum RAM a application may have, maybe that is the problem I solved it by starting and killing programmatically on each request,

Regards,

Corné